# laravel 5.3 old input values always empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

[see docs here about old input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input)

```
Route::post('/search/all/', function (Request $request) {

 //...

  $products = $query->paginate(15);
  $data = ['products' => $products,
  'oldinput' => $request->all()];


  return view('inventory.search_products', $data);
});
```

in the view:

this works:

```
<input type="text"  id="search_all" name="search_all" value="{{ $oldinput['search_all'] }}">
```

this is always empty:

```
<input type="text"  id="search_all" name="search_all"  value="{{ old('search_all') }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `flush` in your **controller** then you can use `old()` helper function in your **blade**.

```
 public function YourController(Request $request){
     $request->flash();
 return view('yourblade');
}
```

**In blade file:-**

```
<input id="lng" name="lng" value="{{old('lng')}}"  type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 2):

docs says you should `flash()` then call `old()` method.

flashing stores the previous request in the session. so it makes sense that `old(search_all)` doesn't work

Comment: so for completeness: the docs are bad because the `->withInput();` only works for redirects. Not for view rendering. So before rendering the view call `$request->flash();`

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest the following solution:

```
return view('inventory.search_products', $data)->withInput(\Input::all());
```

And in blade you can call as well `\Input::old('search_all');`.